# Is there a simple way to test RAII helpers for library that requires Init() and Close() free function calls

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googlemock

I have this library that requires user to call Init() and Close() before using it(for example getting handles).
Luckily Init() and Close() are refcounted so there is no need for keeping track if library is initialized or not.
Now due to convenience and safety(refcount is >0 as long there are handles) I want to make a RAII wrapper for handles, something like

```
void Init(){};
void Close(){};
template<typename H>
void Deregister(H*){};

template<typename H>
struct SafeHandle{
    // requires: caller should make sure that handle is valid handle
    SafeHandle (H* handle): handle_(handle){
         Init();
    }
    ~SafeHandle(){
         handle_->Close();
         Deregister(handle_); // library function for disposing of handles
         Close();
    }
    // delete copy ctor...
    H* const handle_;
};
struct Handle{
    void Close(){};
};

int main() {
    SafeHandle<Handle> i(nullptr);

}
```

Pretty straightforward.
Now the question is how to test this?

One of the things I would do is to create 
ILibrary interface with Open(), Close() Deregister() methods that wrap matching free function, and then GMOCK it in test. 
Secondly I would need to create a test type for handle with counting Close() method.

Is there a better way,?
This seems like quite a lot of testing code for 10 line struct...

note: assume that refcounting is cheap so this design is OK.

Comment: FWIW, you can delete the copy c'tor and copy assigment operator instead of using `H* const handle_;`.  Then you can use a `H* handle_;` and be able to move the objects.

Comment: Who creates the handles, the library or the user of the library?  If it's the library, then I'm confused why the constructor takes a handle before initializing the library.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - user calls some other factory classes to get handles. problem si that when that factory goes out of scope it calls Close() so reference count drops by one, so if you want to use SafeHandle after that it needs to cal Init in constructor of SafeHandle